# print python average with preicision

Tags: python

I am looking to print the average of a data set in python and have the result print with a precision of 8 decimals.

Here is my code now:

```
 avg_to_print = the_sum / the_count

 print 'the average is ' + "%0.8f" % (avg_to_print)
```

This is calculating the correct number for me but for some reason it is only showing the int value (IE: it will show the answer as 100 instead of 100.12345678).

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
avg_to_print = float(the_sum)/the_count
```

It casts the values as floats and then performs the calculations.
In `python-2.7`:

The problem is that you are dividing an int by an int and are getting a int which gets truncated to `100`. Therefore, even if you format it to have `8` decimal places, you will still get `100` which is the problem that you are having.

#### Examples

```
>>> 5/2
2

>>> 5.0/2.0
2.5

>>> 5.0/2
2.5

>>> print ("%0.8f" % (100))
100
```

[Note] As @MarkRansom pointed out, you can also do the following:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 5/2
2.5
```

Comment: You can also use `from __future__ import division` since this behavior is changed in Python 3.